# Query con fechas usando un range

Tags: python, django, sql, django-models

Tengo la query siguiente:

```
query=Detalles.objects.filter(fecha_creacion__range=(fecha_inicio,fecha_final))
```

El resultado esperado es que filtre los resultados comprendidos entre la fecha A y la Fecha B es decir:

```
fechaA= 01-07-2018 FechaB=04-07-2018
```

Sin embargo la query solo retorna hasta el 03-07-2018, es decir hasta un día antes.

Para que retorne hasta el 04-07-2018 es necesario pasar una fecha después, es decir, poner 05-07-2018 para que retorne hasta el 04-07-2018.

Range toma todos los valores entre `FechaA` y `FechaB` pero no sé si me falte especificar algo màs o còmo puedo eficientar mejor la query.

Editado

```
fecha_inicio = request.GET.get('fechaA')
fecha_final  = request.GET.get('fechaB') 


time.min
datetime.time(0, 0)

time.max
datetime.time(23, 59, 59, 999999)

fecha_inicio = datetime.combine(fecha_inicio, time.min)
fecha_final = datetime.combine(fecha_final, time.max)
```

Comment: Hola. El `__range` es inclusivo por lo que debería considerar hasta el `04-07-2018`. ¿Tal vez tu campo `fecha_creación` es un `DateTimeField` en vez de un `DateField`?

Comment: Si, efectivamente es un DateTimeField ¿pero entonces cuando usar: DateTimeField  y cuando usar: DateField?

Comment: Lo explico en mi respuesta.

Answer (score 1):

Ahora veo cuál es el problema. Me parece que es correcto que uses un `DateTimeField` para fechas de creación. El problema es que estás usando fechas tipo `date`: `01-07-2018` y `04-07-2018`. Lo que deberías estar usando son fechas del tipo `datetime` que incluyen la hora.

Imagina que tienes esto:

```
>>> from datetime import date
>>> fecha_inicio = date(2018, 7, 1)
>>> fecha_final = date(2018, 7, 4)
```

Lo que va pasar cuando lo pases por el query es que se les va agregar un `00:00:00` (no estoy seguro si esto lo hace Django o el motor de la base de datos, habría que confirmarlo). Por lo tanto, en tu query tendrías: `2018-07-01 00:00:00` y `2018-07-04 00:00:00` respectivamente.

Para el caso de la fecha inicial `2018-07-01 00:00:00` estaría bien porque estás buscando desde el inicio del día, pero para el caso de la fecha final `2018-07-04 00:00:00` estarías buscando solo hasta el primer minuto del día 04. Es por eso que no tienes resultados para ese día.

La solución es usar [`datetime.combine`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.combine):

```
>>> from datetime import date, datetime, time
>>> fecha_inicio = date(2018, 7, 1)
>>> fecha_final = date(2018, 7, 4)
>>> print fecha_inicio
2018-07-01
>>> print fecha_final
2018-07-04
>>> time.min
datetime.time(0, 0)
>>> time.max
datetime.time(23, 59, 59, 999999)
>>> fecha_inicio = datetime.combine(fecha_inicio, time.min)
>>> fecha_final = datetime.combine(fecha_final, time.max)
>>> print fecha_inicio
2018-07-01 00:00:00
>>> print fecha_final
2018-07-04 23:59:59.999999
```

Usando `datetime.time.min` y `datetime.time.max`, que representan la primera y la última hora del día, hemos "combinado" las fechas para que usen estos valores. Ahora estoy seguro que tu query dará resultado ya que estamos usando hasta el último minuto del día 4.

Comment: Gracias! Acabo de editar los cambios con las observaciones que mencionas, sin embargo me marca: descriptor 'time' requires a 'datetime.datetime' object but received a 'int'

Comment: @NetzaL creo que estás confundiendo el módulo. `datetime.datetime.time` no es el mismo que `datetime.time`. Tienes que usar el último.

Answer (score 0):

Si lo que buscas es sumar un día puedes usar pandas

```
fecha_final = pd.to_datetime(date(2018, 7, 4), format="%Y-%m-%d") + pd.DateOffset(day=1)
```